# Avoiding Overflow in python 3.5

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was used to Matlab, so when I want to create an array of `10**j` in Python, where `j` is an integer, I use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array(range(11))
b=10**a
```

However my machine gives me the following output:

```
array([          1,          10,         100, ...,   100000000,
    1000000000, -2147483648], dtype=int32)
```

The last entry is obviously wrong. Now, I know I can do the following

```
b=np.array([10**k for k in range(11)])
```

which gives the correct answer, so I guess the problem is from the numpy function `array` (Of course, I can avoid this problem by saving `a` as a `int64` integer, but there will be overflow problem for larger `j`). It seems like there could be a lot of situations where one could fall into this pitfall of overflowed integers when doing mathematical operations on arrays. I am wondering whether there are ways to avoid this problem?

Comment: note that you can also use `np.arange(11, dtype='int32')`

Comment: is there a reason you can't use floats?  That is usually the solution when dealing with large exponents with a small number of significant digits.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt thought of that...silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't really a way to avoid this problem because numpy deliberatly not checks for overflow in some arithmetic operations because it's faster not to check. Generally you need to pay attention to what kind of objects you represent in numpy.

However you could force an `object`-array, to get Python behaviour:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(range(15), object)   
>>> # Note: You could also use "a = np.arange(15, dtype=object)" instead! Thanks @TheBlackCat
>>> b = 10 ** a
>>> b
array([1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000,
       1000000000, 10000000000, 100000000000, 1000000000000,
       10000000000000, 100000000000000], dtype=object)
```

Note that `object` arrays are slow and should only be used if you don't need the full-numpy-speed and functionality.

In your specific case you can also use the `np.float_power`-ufunc:

```
b = np.float_power(10, a)
b
array([  1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+01,   1.00000000e+02,
         1.00000000e+03,   1.00000000e+04,   1.00000000e+05,
         1.00000000e+06,   1.00000000e+07,   1.00000000e+08,
         1.00000000e+09,   1.00000000e+10,   1.00000000e+11,
         1.00000000e+12,   1.00000000e+13,   1.00000000e+14])
```

Comment: You can also use `np.arange(15, dtype='object')`

Comment: @TheBlackCat You're right! I just copied and modified the code from the question. I'll edit the answer.